# Playground execution failed:

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, xcode7-beta6

I'm trying to use playground in xcode 7 to test some code but for some reason it won't run.

This is the error I'm getting

Playground execution failed: /var/folders/q6/zswv_4wj16zbckfbdtl9lmyh0000gp/T/./lldb/11352/playground14.swift:1:8: error: module file's minimum deployment target is ios9.0 v9.0: /var/folders/q6/zswv_4wj16zbckfbdtl9lmyh0000gp/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/auxiliarymodules/C2294E15-2E60-47B3-8A0B-DABB2C0C3D88/MyPlayground_Sources.framework/Modules/MyPlayground_Sources.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule
import MyPlayground_Sources

This is the very simple code I'm trying to execute.

```
class testClass{
    var property = "some property"
}
var test = testClass()
test.property
```

What does it mean by module file's minimum deployment target is ios9.0?

Comment: Try restarting Xcode.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what the problem is.

I opened an Xcode 6 playground file in Xcode 7.

When I create a new playground in Xcode 7 it works fine.

Comment: Interesting…for future reference, Xcode 6 doesn't play well with Xcode 7.